# Google Calendar API get events for current day node.js

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api

Trying to get current days events using timeMin and timeMax with google calendar API, but for some reason it isnt working if theyre the same day (today). I kinda get why, it cant get the events for the same day because as per documentation, Min needs to be smaller than Max. Any way around this?

This is what Im doing right now

```
var now = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ")
//var yesterday = moment().subtract(1, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ")
//var tomorrow = moment().add(1, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ")


const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth});
calendar.events.list({

calendarId: 'primary',
timeMin: (now),
timeMax: (now),
maxResults: 10,
singleEvents: true,
orderBy: 'startTime',
}, (err, res) => {
if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
const events = res.data.items;
```

running it like this, will return no events for the day. As you can see I also tried doing yesterday and tomorrow and sandwich to today in between the two, but it also gets yesterdays and tomorrows events, which isnt what I want obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i may be dumb, all i had to do was change the format for the moment variables, create 2 variables one for the start of the day, one for then end of the day

```
var beginning = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:01:00Z")
var end = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDT23:59:00Z")
```

Doing this solved what I needed to do